Dark spots on leaves of dogwood tree
About three weeks ago I planted a white dogwood tree.
The plant survived one night of frost, but then the leaves began to darken and dry as in the photo.
Is this a fungus?
What can I do in this situation?
I'm afraid it will all be over in a few days.


